# Getting XSLT to add Doctype System to XML output file

Tags: xml, xslt, doctype

I'm quite new at XML and am trying to get an XSLT to add a doctype-system to a .DTD file contained within the same folder as the .XML that's being transformed.

The transformation is being carried out by InDesign.

I just can't get it to add for example 
underneath the xml version.

I've been trying to get this for a couple of days now and it's just stumped me. I've searched the forum and I couldn't find a solution so apologies if this has been asked before

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Transformation code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-system="name.dtd" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<CATEGORY>
    <VERS>
        <xsl:for-each select="VFPData/g_otemp/prodid">
        <xsl:sort select="../priceout" data-type="number" />
        <xsl:if test="../inactive != 'true'">
            <code>
                <xsl:value-of select="../prodid" />
            </code>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="../desc" />
            </name>
            <xsl:if test="../priceout != '0.0000'">
                <price>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(../priceout, '£0.00')" />
                </price>
            </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="../priceout = '0.0000'">
            <price>P.O.A</price>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
        <loc>&amp;name;</loc>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </VERS>
</CATEGORY>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

.DTD File (Contains placeholder text atm)

```
<!ENTITY name "I'm in the same folder as my XML Data">
```

File Being Transformed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<VFPData>
  <g_otemp>
    <prodid>AAV-502430</prodid>
    <desc>3/8" Automatic Air Vent - 4 Bar</desc>
    <data21>4</data21>
    <priceout>7.7600</priceout>
    <pricecost>3.1900</pricecost>
    <profit>4.5700</profit>
    <pricedesc>Price Update - JCR</pricedesc>
    <price_from>2017-01-19T11:42:00</price_from>
    <vatrate>20.00</vatrate>
    <maingroup>AAV's &amp; ELIMINATORS</maingroup>
    <prodgroup2>Automatic Air Vents</prodgroup2>
    <pk_prodid>7520</pk_prodid>
    <inactive>false</inactive>
  </g_otemp>
  <g_otemp>
    <prodid>AAV-502630</prodid>
    <desc>3/8" Automatic Air Vent - 10 Bar</desc>
    <data21>4</data21>
    <priceout>8.2800</priceout>
    <pricecost>3.7967</pricecost>
    <profit>4.4833</profit>
    <pricedesc>Price Update - JCR</pricedesc>
    <price_from>2017-08-14T10:49:00</price_from>
    <vatrate>20.00</vatrate>
    <maingroup>AAV's &amp; ELIMINATORS</maingroup>
    <prodgroup2>Automatic Air Vents</prodgroup2>
    <pk_prodid>5562</pk_prodid>
    <inactive>false</inactive>
  </g_otemp>
</VFPData>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the desired output would look like. When I test the code, the current output is: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE CATEGORY
  SYSTEM "name.dtd">
<CATEGORY xmlns:fn`.

Comment: You don't say exactly what output you are seeing. If there is no `<!DOCTYPE` in the output, then my suspicion would be that you are running the transformation without serialization (for example, you are writing the result tree to a DOM). So please indicate how you run the transformation.

Comment: @MichaelKay I'm using the built in Transformation feature in adobe InDesign (you import the XML file and it then gives you the option to use a XSLT and to choose which XSLT file you would like to use.)

If add doctype-system into XSL output
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" doctype-system="name.dtd"/>
it gives me the error "Not well formed. Line: 1, Column: 30"

I need it to be able to reference the same folder that the XML is stored in. As what I want to do is have it reference its own file location.

Comment: My suggestion would be: see if you can make it work outside the inDesign environment. If you can, you know that it's then an inDesign problem, which means you need to tackle it a different way.

Comment: @MichaelKay After some experimentation it does appear to be an InDesign issue as running the code through some online transformers seems to make it work ok. Thank you very much for taking the time to have a look at this for me, it's gratefully appreciated.

Comment: @zx485 thank you for looking as well :)